# Convert Java Socket, BufferedReader, BufferedWriter to C#?

Tags: c#, java

In Java we have Socket, BufferedReader and BufferedWriter, but what are the equivalent in C#?

```
Socket socket;
socket = new Socket(address, port);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Are you looking for *equivalent* classes or the C#-way of reading chars from a remote server?

Comment: As close to as I can get, but I realize It'll never be fully equivalent. Thanx for asking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# you have [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) classes. But you also have higher level classes that don't require you to resort to sockets such as [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). Here's an example that connects to a listening socket and opens a stream reader that allows you to read from it:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient(address, port))
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
     // TODO: Read from the network stream
}
```